# gitlab -> git push -u origin master ->access denied, fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, centos, gitlab

I am using gitlab to manage git connections. And here is my problem:

```
root@ubuntu:/tmp/test1/test1# git push -u origin master
Access denied.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I also checked gitlab-shell.log, here is the content:

```
W, [2015-01-13T16:47:13.252992 #26662]  WARN -- : gitlab-shell: Access denied for git command <git-receive-pack 'Jianyong/test1.git'> by user with key key-8.
```

My host is running CentOS 6.6 and here is my gitlab environment :

```
System information
System:     CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
Current User:   root
Using RVM:  no
Ruby Version:   2.0.0p353
Gem Version:    2.0.14
Bundler Version:1.7.12
Rake Version:   10.1.0

GitLab information
Version:    6.4.3
Revision:   3173626    
Directory:  /home/git/gitlab 
DB Adapter: mysql2
URL:        http://gitlab.glodon-ci.com
HTTP Clone URL: http://gitlab.glodon-ci.com/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@gitlab.glodon-ci.com:some-project.git
Using LDAP: no
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:    1.9.6
Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
Hooks:      /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:        /usr/bin/git
```

Then I also tried:

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.glodon-ci.com
```

It logged that 'Welcome to Gitlab, admin!'

what's wrong?

Comment: What do you mean you tried `git@localhost`? Does the `user with key key-8` have access rights to the `Jianyong/test1.git` repository?

Comment: How is `review.gitlab.com` connected to `gitlab.glodon-ci.com`? And no, but I would imagine that's a gitlab admin interface task.

Comment: My god. I am so sorry, it is 'ssh -T git@gitlab.glodon-ci.com'. i try to modify it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few days, i solved it finally.
  Pay attention to several aspects of the gitlab. Here is that:

1. if you used apache reverse proxy, you should edit `/home/git/gitlab-shell/config.yml`.
      `gitlab_url = "http://youraddress:port"`
2. if you used centos or radhat os which uses selinux mechanism , you should change it from enforcing to permissive.
3. Make sure that you have pasted public key to gitlab by using you username and email.
4. Make sure that your gitlab, gitlab-shell, redis services are running well. if these do not works well, you should read log files to get some useful information.
5. Then, if you have edited some configure files, you should restart services. Do not forget it.